# The use of programming in artificial intelligence

Tags: c++, c, artificial-intelligence

What are the programming languages we can use in the development of an artificial intelligent system? which operating system should be used? can C or C++ programming languages be used?

Comment: Dunno why this was -1ed.

Answer (score 6):

- What are the programming languages we can use in the development of an artificial intelligent system?

Prolog is a good start for reasoning systems. Lisp is a good start for symbolic systems. Both of those can be embedded in other languages, e.g., C++.

- which operating system should be used?

Er.... any?

- can C or C++ programming languages be used?

Yes.

You probably want to learn more about programming before you tackle AI.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. And it's a good choice too, because it can be made pretty well performing (which is the main problem in developing a good AI).

But there is no limitation, really. Any language will do.

Comment: Based on your remark that good performance is "the main problem" in AI development, I suspect you have interpreted "AI" to mean "AI controlling computer players or pathfinding in a computer game", but that's just one possible application.  "The main problem" in the broader field of AI is that despite massive increases in computing power, outside a handful of tasks computers are still terrible at doing many of the things that human brains routinely do (e.g. speech recognition).

Comment: @j_random_hacker - exactly. Because the brain is so massively parallel, contemporary computers just don't have the power to emulate that. If we could simulate 50 billion neurons and a quadrillion synapses, we'd have no problems with the tasks you mentioned. But as it is, computers are massively underpowered for such endeavors, which means that every increase in performance will bring better results for all such tasks. It's really the computing power that is the limitation for any but the most trivial AIs of today.

Comment: Thus, an algorithm or environment that can perform better, can also get better results at AI tasks. They'll still suck at it, but they'll suck a little less than their lesser-performant brothers.

Answer (score 1):

Just about any language can be used but you want one that works well with your specific domain, and you are comfortable with using.

As already mentioned, PROLOG and LISP are both traditional AI languages. General purpose languages such as Java, C#, and C++ also have their uses.
Also if you are looking at aural language processing, then a language that is good at text processing and data structures would be ideal. Eg. Python and the NLTK toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Although some languages are more strongly associated with AI programming than others -- e.g., LISP, Prolog -- many different languages can be used.

Any of the general-purpose operating systems may be used.

You can use a procedural language like C. An OO language like C++, Java or C# offers some advantages. Functional and logical languages are also worth considering.

Personally, I've written one A-B game-playing program now in LISP, Java and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Any language can be used to develop Artificial Intelligence, AI, applications; some make implementing the AI concepts easier than others.

Some old time favorites are LISP and Prolog.

If you are well versed in C or C++, then use either one to implement the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to learn AI programming you should pick a language where you can concentrate on the problem domain instead of the language.

For example in a typical C program about half of the code concerns itself with memory management and error handling. By using a language that supports garbage collection and exceptions you can reduce this amount drastically.

The choice of language also depends on prior works. Are there any or do you want to start from scratch? If the prior works seem to be good, you can hope that they already chose an appropriate language.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the niche you are interested in, but C++ is probably the most popular language for artificial intelligence. You will find that most libraries are written for it.

You can use languages other than C++, too. Functional languages, such as LISP and F# are good choices for AI, because they offer good tools for decomposing complicated logic.

The operating system is not much of an issue. Whether you choose Windows, Unix, or Mac, you will find a few libraries that are not cross-platform and unavailable for your platform.